# Base 64 : Illegal base64 character 3 Exception

Tags: java, base64, decode, base64url

I have a text file with a base64 encoded value, and I tried to decode that text file and save it into a PDF format.
Below is my code

```
File inputfile = new File('/Users/Downloads/DownloadedPDF.txt')
File outputfile = new File('/Users/Downloads/test64.pdf')
byte[] data
try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputfile)
    data = new byte[(int) inputfile.length()]
    fileInputStream.read(data)
    fileInputStream.close()
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.getStackTrace()
}
//Decode the data
byte[] decoded = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(data)
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputfile)
    //Write the decoded details to the output file [pdf format]
    fileOutputStream.write(decoded)
    fileOutputStream.flush()
    fileOutputStream.close()
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.getStackTrace()
}
```

While executing the code I received the below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3
    at java_util_Base64$Decoder$decode$0.call(Unknown Source)
```

i tried the below one using the URL decoder, but still received the same error.

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(data)
```

Comment: What is the data you are trying to decode?

Comment: Is this Groovy or Kotlin? That doesn't look like valid Java code (no semicolons).

Comment: have you tried running the encoded data through some other base64 decoder to verify that it is actually valid?

Comment: @DavidConrad This is Groovy script;

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `inputfile.length()` to return the true size of the file, although it might. I would use [InputStream::readAllBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()) instead.

Comment: If it's Groovy then it should be tagged [tag:groovy] rather than [tag:java].

Comment: @DavidConrad `File.length()` _should_ give you a valid file length.

Comment: @jtahlborn I agree, it *should*. Actually, I think you're right, it's probably the `read()` call, not the `length()` call.

Comment: @khelwood Given this is using a Java API, tagging with [tag:java] seems appropriate, though adding [tag:groovy] would be recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Reading bytes from a stream does not guarantee that it will read *all* the bytes you request.  try `readNBytes()` instead.  (or you can use `readAllBytes()` as mentioned by @DavidConrad).

Comment: Or `readAllBytes()`.

Comment: Or [wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#wrap(java.io.InputStream)) the input stream so it decodes on the fly, instead of loading the entire base64 in memory before decoding. The OP can then use [`transferTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)) to write to the destination file, removing the need for materializing the entire file in memory as well. (Although I'd question a system where a PDF was saved in a base64 encoded text file to begin with.)